# Eclipse RCP export: The signature is invalid for current content

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

Struggling to export RCP product from the Eclipse 4.31.0 (Build id: 20240307-1437), using target platform built from https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2024-03.

Getting "**The signature is invalid for current content**" from the pde build:

```
[p2.director] Installing com.foo.client.product 5.2.4.
[p2.director] Overall install request is satisfiable
[p2.director] Add request for logFaces 5.2.4 (com.foo.client.product 5.2.4) is satisfiable
[p2.director] Installation failed.
[p2.director] An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
[p2.director]   session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
[p2.director]   Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.sun.jna,5.14.0.v20231211-1200.
[p2.director]       The signature is invalid for current content
[p2.director] An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
[p2.director] session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
[p2.director] Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.sun.jna,5.14.0.v20231211-1200.
A problem occured while invoking the director.
runDirector:  duration 0 seconds
```

(I know what I am using pde build ant, which isn't actively supported but we can't migrate to Tycho build at the moment. )

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [tag:tycho] is the only supported way to build RCPs these days. The old export is not being maintained.

Comment: This looks the same as [this issue](https://github.com/eclipse-equinox/p2/issues/457) but the advice there is to use tycho.

Comment: @greg-449 As I said, Tycho is not something we can use. Anyone else have an insight into this issue please? It looks like something trivial in the repository or the platform I am building against.

Comment: You can and should build your RCP application with Tycho. I wasted time by switching to Tycho far too late which was years ago. Switching to Tycho is easier than you think and you will get help if you get stuck, unlike for PDE Build which is not supported at all for years.